# Kendo validator seems ignore pattern attribute (regex)

Tags: jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc, html, kendo-ui

```html
<input id="myID" 
       name="myName" 
       class="form-control k-invalid" 
       data-bind="value: ViewModel.JobNo, visible: Layout.isEditMode"
       required="required" 
       data-required-msg="The Job No. field is required." 
       pattern="\d{10}" 
>
```

I have an input element as above in a form, which I want to force user to enter 10 digit numbers.

I simply add a `pattern = "\d{10}"` and thought when I called `validator.validate()`, it will handle the validation for me, but seems it's not the case, indeed the `pattern` rule is always ignored while the `required` rule works perfectly.

I tried to verify it, so I opend developer console in Chrome, and typed the following:

```js
$("#myID").kendoValidator();
$("#myID").data("kendoValidator").validate()
```

If I leave the field empty, this will give me false, and say it is required (good).

But if I have typed in some numbers, or any other strings which should violate the pattern, this still gives me true and gets pass the validation.

What did I do wrong, and how can I achieve what I wanted? Thanks!

Comment: Although this isn't a solution to your overall problem, if you want the user to just enter a 10 digit number, then your current expression will allow 10 or more digits somewhere in your string of random numbers. I'd change your expression from `\d{10}` to `^\d{10}$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is probably because you are missing the `type` attribute from `input` tag. Adding a `type` attribute should fix the issue.

```
<input id="myID" 
       type="text" <!-- enter what ever type of input it is-->
       name="myName" 
       class="form-control k-invalid" 
       data-bind="value: ViewModel.JobNo, visible: Layout.isEditMode"
       required="required" 
       data-required-msg="The Job No. field is required." 
       pattern="\d{10}" 
>
```

I made a [telerik dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/AGEQO) using an existing example just to show the working. The first input has no type and hence pattern validation doesn't work, but it works on second input.

Comment: Omg thanks so much, did not know it is a must-have field to achieve this...You saved my day !

Comment: Nice, that was it for me. That feels like a bug in Kendo Validator. Input type is "text" by default: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-input-type